# Searching and Printing within an arrayList

Tags: java, search, arraylist

So, I've written a method to search an arrayList for a specific word within a title (the title is an element within the arrayList books of type ). I then need to print the titles that contain that word. Here is the code I have:

```
public void getBook(ArrayList<Book> books) {
    // find and create new arraylist with just books with "cat"
    for (Book b : books) {
        for (int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++) {
            if (b.getTitle().contains("cat")) {

                System.out.println(b.getTitle());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So at this point, nothing prints. Is it an error within my loop? Or am I going about searching and printing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, strings don't have a method like .equalsIgnoreCase(). So, first you need to convert the title to lower or upper case. In this way you can found titles that contains certain words.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList();
        books.add(new Book("The mistery of cat"));
        books.add(new Book("Category"));
        books.add(new Book("Titanic"));
        books.add(new Book("Adjudicated"));
        getBook(books);
}

public static void getBook(ArrayList<Book> books) {
    for (Book b : books) {
        if (b.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains("cat")) {
            System.out.println(b.getTitle());
        }
    }
}
```

You'll get:

> The mistery of cat,
>   Category,
>   Adjudicated,

Comment: string class has `equalsIgnoreCase`https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-

Comment: Sorry, I tried to say "strings don't have other method similar to.equalsIgnoreCase()"

Comment: @Hasho, update your code and remove this line ` strings don't have a method like .equalsIgnoreCase().`.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the nested for loops if you are just looking for a single word in an `ArrayList`. In your case the title will print multiple times because it is inside a nested loop.

I don't see anything wrong with this code otherwise. I suggest adding a `System.out.println(b.getTitle());` to see what titles are coming through.

Try the code below and see what results you get. This will see if everything else in your program is correct.

```
public void getBook(ArrayList<Book> books) {
    for (Book b : books) {
        System.out.println(b.getTitle());
        if (b.getTitle().contains("cat")) {
            System.out.println("Found successfully");
        }
    }
}
```

If titles aren't printed, then there could be a problem with your `Book` class or with how you're setting up your `ArrayList`.

Comment: So when I try that code, it just prints all of the titles in the entire arrayList, not the ones containing the specific word. To me, this shows it isn't actually going through to find the word, ie getting to the "if" statement

Comment: So titles with "cat" in them were shown in the original list but no "Found successfully" was shown?

Comment: All titles, both with and without cat were shown, but found successfully never printed.

Comment: What does your `getTitle()` method look like? Does it return a `String`?

Comment: Yes, getTitle() returns a string